# How to store Call Logs

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Voip app using Sip account  which received Call Logs,but i want to store call logs, when i closed app and reload again call logs removed from recyclerview cell. I'm using Linphone library, to get CallLogs. 
How can i store  Call Logs.

```
class CallHistoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            mLogs = Arrays.asList(LinphoneManager.getLc().getCallLogs());
            return mLogs.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mLogs.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = null;
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (convertView != null) {
                view = convertView;
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            } else {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.history_cell, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder(view);
                view.setTag(holder);

            }
            if (mLogs == null || mLogs.size() < position)


                return view;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sqlite or alternative to save call logs.
[Tutorial to save data](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm)

Comment: Can I use firebase instead of sqlite

Comment: Yes, you can use firebase for it too. There is a firebase offline service too, sothat you can save your data offline and online. I think,  firebase is much better option if you have a firebase plan and familiar with it. Here is a firebase documentation about firebase offline: firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html